# MonoTouch binding to derived NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, xamarin.ios, nsmanagedobject

I have some existing code in ObjC that I would like to use in a MonoTouch app. I am creating a static lib from the existing code and then using binding to access and use it from the MonoTouch app. Everything is working great except when I attempt to bind to a type derived from NSManagedObject. For some reason it cannot find the property. I get an "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error. I'm guessing it has something to do with @dynamic, but I'm not sure and couldn't find any documentation regarding why this doesn't work.

**.h**

```
@interface MyNSManagedObject : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *clientName;

@end
```

**.m**

```
@implementation MyNSManagedObject

@dynamic clientName;

@end
```

Comment: Can you post the interface definition? It would help getting a reply